# android OAuth question, how to send request for request token

Tags: android, oauth

in Don Park's example :http://donpark.org/blog/2009/01/24/android-client-side-oauth

I am confused about step2.

there is such a lane:

```
OAuthAccessor defaultClient() {
String callbackUrl = "icecondor-android-app:///";
OAuthServiceProvider provider =  defaultProvider(ctx);
OAuthConsumer consumer = new OAuthConsumer(callbackUrl, consumerKey,
                                consumerSecret, provider);
OAuthAccessor accessor = new OAuthAccessor(consumer);
OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new HttpClient4());
}
```

I dont know where did we send request for request token?
where is the return ? should we return accessor?

I think there should be something like client.excute(request_url and parameters) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are partially correct, he seems to have omitted that step. You need to use your oauth key,secret,timestamp,etc and send a request to the API to obtain the request token.

[Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) is java library that I have successfully used on Android to simplify using OAuth.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly should I do with Singpost? to run don Park's code? 
Looks like  Singposit use 
      String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);
to send request? and then user bufferread to read the inputstream(request token?)

Comment: Ignore Don Park's code. Check out the Twitter Example with Signpost.
http://github.com/kaeppler/signpost-examples/blob/master/OAuthTwitterExample/src/TwitterMain.java

Comment: I want to write android app which communicate with opensocial, so I have to figure out how can I send the request for request token, I checked  twitter and google example from signpost, but I still cant understand  how this work. 
 String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);
I need to find out how the client code to send request and recieve request token from server.